# Django - JQuery autocomplete custom select from multiple fields

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a user search that autocompletes by both ticker and name. The search results come back as "{{ticker}} - {{name}}". When a result is selected, I want it to fill with only the ticker, where as it currently fills with "{{ticker}} - {{name}}".

Here is my python code:

```
if 'term' in request.GET:
    tickers = Company.objects.filter(ticker__istartswith = request.GET.get('term')) | Company.objects.filter(name__istartswith = request.GET.get('term'))
    companies = []
    for ticker in tickers:
        companyTicker = ticker.ticker +  " - " + ticker.name
        companies.append(companyTicker)
    return JsonResponse(companies, safe=False)
```

and here is my javascript:

```
    <script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#ticker3" ).autocomplete({
        source: '{% url "financials:get_financials" %}',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            ticker.ticker
        }
      });
    } );
    </script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could return companyTicker as a dict in your json response. That way you could easily reference ticker and name independent of one another. `companyTicker = {'ticker': ticker.ticker, 'name': ticker.name}`

Comment: Are you able to give a full example as an answer? I tried that but still can't figure out how to use that as the selector.

Comment: I'm sorry. My above comment doesn't work with the jquery autocomplete function. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the [jquery autocomplete docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) reveals that you can use an array of objects for your `source` option. Each object should have a `label` and `value` attribute. The following should get you what you need.

```
if 'term' in request.GET:
    tickers = Company.objects.filter(ticker__istartswith = request.GET.get('term')) | Company.objects.filter(name__istartswith = request.GET.get('term'))
    companies = []
    for ticker in tickers:
        label = f"{ticker.ticker} - {ticker.name}"
        companyTicker = {'label': label, 'value': ticker.ticker}
        companies.append(companyTicker)
    return JsonResponse(companies, safe=False)
```

You can then remove the `select` option in your javascript:

```
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#ticker3").autocomplete({
              source: '{% url "financials:get_financials" %}',
          });
      });
  </script>
```